# Debugging Embedded PythonScripts in IronPython what practical ways do i have?

Tags: debugging, scripting, ironpython

In our product we are using PTVS and IronPython
for scripting. All the scripts reside in the customers database,
are loaded from there and then execute via the Execute Function.
We are now searching ways to make debugging these scripts easier.
Most of the time we are using Remote Connections to our customers
using TeamViewer and software like that.

In the current state the only way to debug we have, is using ShowMessageBox
for the content of variables.

Is there any other way to debug these scripts, maybe using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Add more than MessageBox.
Add utility logging messages so they can debug their badly written loops.
Info() Warn() Error()
This will help debugging more than breakpoints and other debugging mechanisms.
Also use the ExceptionOperations FormatException method for all trapped exceptions to get python line information.
[Catching Ironpython Exception in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614365/catching-ironpython-exception-in-c-sharp)

All this plus an editor control that shows line numbers and you should be able to debug to some degree.